# mvn package ignoring repository in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, repository, nexus

We cannot get a project to pull from a remote repository using mvn package. In maven installed folder, config/settings.xml we declare our internal central repo:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>advnexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://internalserver/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

This works for all of the jar files hosted at this repo. But we have some additional jar files we pushed to a server under our control and running Sonatype Nexus. So in the project's pom.xml, we setup our remote repo as:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>companynamenexus</id>
    <name>Company Name Project Repo</name>
    <url>http://nexus.companyname.com:8081/repository/project-name</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <spanshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </spanshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I run the build, it pulls any needed jar files from the main repo, but simply times out trying to pull the jar files that don't exist on this repo vs. using the repository in the pom.xml.

Note that in the settings.xml mirror section, I tried changing the `<mirrorOf>` to be central vs. *, but this just caused additional errors.

I have also tried setting up this repo as a secondary mirror in the settings.xml, tried commenting out the mirror in the settings.xml and place it as an additional repository in the pom.xml, all without finding the right combination.  Seems like a simple problem, but the answer is eluding us.

Comment: Is the repo available at `http://nexus.companyname.com:8081/repository/project-name`? If you time out maybe the nexus is down or the `repository/project-name` is not a valid path?

Comment: Unfortunately, both repos are internal and cannot be accessed from outside. Also, the timeout is occurring during the build when it tried to pull the jars from the mirror, which don't exist. It doesn't appear to ever try and use the repo in the pom.xml.

Comment: Some additional info. Though you cannot access the files via the same URL you put into the url field for the repo, Sonatype Nexus does provide a REST endpoint in the format: 'http://nexus.companyname:8081/service/rest/repository/browse/project-name' and this can be accessed via a browser. Note that just for giggles, I tried using this as the URL, but same result.

Comment: If you have already a repository manager than I don't understand the need of adding a supplemental repository in a pom file. Artifacts are identified by groupId/artifactId/version which means there is no need for a supplemental repository entry ...the Repo Manager should provide that in it's configuration if the needed repo is really a supplemental repo (which is a design issue in the Nexus setup)...

Comment: The Sonatype Nexus repo has been setup only to make internal company jar files accessible for builds. There is also a company provided "Central" repository which contains jar files pulled from the real Maven Central. That said, I'm now back to trying to setup both our repositories in the mirrors section of the settings.xml file. I believe my issue is with the mirrorOf selections.  In other words, I'm not sure if I should be setting up this project Nexus Repo in the mirrors section of the settings.xml or the repositories section of the pom.xml!?

Comment: If your issue is with a snapshot version, it might be because you wrote SPANshots instead of SNAPshots in your POM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution: Don't try to access two different internal Nexus, but set up a repository group in one of the Nexus that contains all other repositories (may they be hosted or proxy, internal or external). Then you can simply set a mirror entry on that repository group and you are fine.

Second best solution: Change your mirror entry to `<mirrorOf>*,!companynamenexus</mirrorOf>` and define the additional repository in the `<repositories>` section of your `settings.xml`.

Comment: This looked like it had promise, but now I am getting a new error when running a 'mvn package'. It appears our Sonatype Nexus repo is trying to reach out to 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 (which cannot be reached on our network, not even with a proxy). It needs to download 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.4'. If I had a clue where to put this jar, I can move it over to our network manually, but don't see anything giving me a clue. I believe this was caused when I selected maven2(group) and (proxy). I just saw there is a (raw) type and am going to try that next.

Comment: Final followup. The 'raw' type would not work, but we will proceed with downloading that jar manually for sonatype and believe it should work. Thx for your help!

Comment: I cannot really follow you. Nexus is trying to reach repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 if this is one of the configured repositories in Nexus. You cannot add it accidentally and it has nothing to do with the repository type.